# Maintaining two databases in one application with spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a use case where i have to keep some data in remote db however i would be having reference of the data in local `enter code here`db, insertion is happening properly in remote db but when i'm trying to access the data from the remote db i'm unable to fetch the data, here i'm specifying my few code snippets.

**persistence.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />

    <!-- Added this additional line to share the connection Pool -->
    <!-- <property name="initialSize" value="1000" /> <property name="maxActive" 
        value="1000" /> <property name="maxIdle" value="10" /> -->
</bean>

<!-- This is the new Properties for the new DB of aadhaar vault -->
<bean id="myDataSource1"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${db1.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db1.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db1.password}" />

    <!-- Added this additional line to share the connection Pool -->
    <!-- <property name="initialSize" value="1000" /> <property name="maxActive" 
        value="1000" /> <property name="maxIdle" value="10" /> -->
</bean>

<!-- This is the new DB table, which is being initialized for the aadhaar 
    vault -->

<bean id="mySessionFactory1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource1" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernateNew.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <!-- Specify session context -->
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop> -->

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<!-- This is the new DB table, which is being initialized for the  
    remote , ends here -->


<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <!-- Specify session context -->
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop> -->

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManagerNew"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory1" />
</bean>

<bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.abc.def.model.User"></mapping>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**hibernateNew.cfg.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.abc.def.model.User1"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**config.properties**

```
db1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    db1.username=root
    db1.password=password

db1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/old_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
db1.username=root
db1.password=root
```

**ABCService.Java**

```
 @Service
public class ABCServiceImpl implements ABCService {

    @Autowired
    ABCDao abcDao;
    @Override
    @Transactional("transactionManagerNew")
    public ABC getByForeignKey(Long refid,Long customerEntityId) {

        return abcDao.getByForeignKey(refid,customerEntityId);
    }
```

**ABCDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class ABCDaoImpl implements ABCDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mySessionFactory1")
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public ABC getByForeignKey(Long refId,Long customerEntityId) {
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(" from ABC where RefId = " + refId + " and customerEntityId = "+customerEntityId);
        List<ABC> abcs = query.list();
        if(abcs.size()>0) {
            return abcs.get(0);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

here i'm trying to access the value from the new_db which always returns me null values,
any help would be highly appreciated. I'm dealing with this from last 2 days yet not found any solution, please let me know if some more snippets is required.

Comment: where is the select?

Comment: @YCF_L i'm using hibernate, so it in itself manages

Comment: what rdbms you are using? did you test the query in your rdbms?

Comment: @YCF_L i'm using MySql, however my query is running properly within my db environment.

Comment: are you sure that `refId` and `customerEntityId` not null?

Comment: @YCF_L, yeah it has some relevant data, i have already mentioned that insertion is not a problem problem is fetching the data.